# pass parameter to click event of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<div style="float:left">
  <div class="d-inline ">
    <i id="reply@{@item.Id}" class="bi bi-reply icon-cursor test-comment" onclick="CommentReply(@item.Id)"></i>
  </div>                            
</div>
```

and js

```
 function CommentReply(id)
 {
    //to do something
 }
```

but I want to change to

```
  $(".test-comment").click(function () {
    //to do something

    // I need Id in here
})
```

how can I pass the Id parameter to test-comment click event?

Comment: Add a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) containing the *id* like `data-id="{@item.Id}"` and access it inside the click handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with data attributes: test code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k8roaLpc/)

HTML

```
<div style="float:left">
  <div class="d-inline ">
    <i data-id="10" data-xx="other x" class="bi bi-reply icon-cursor test-comment" >some text</i> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Remove onclick= ... and  use data-* for your info.

JS

```
$(".test-comment").click(function () {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
    alert($(this).data("xx"));
})
```

snippet <3

```js
$(".test-comment").click(function () {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
    alert($(this).data("xx"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left">
  <div class="d-inline ">
    <i data-id="10" data-xx="other x" class="bi bi-reply icon-cursor test-comment" >CLICK ME!</i> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why a fiddle instead of a snippet.

Comment: Because I'm very old.  I'll try snippet soon. Thx

Comment: Click snippet - copy html/js/css from fiddle, choose jquery on the left (of snippet) if it's not in your html on the fiddle, then click tidy and save.  If you have a fiddle, it's easy :)

Comment: Added snippet! Thx =)

Answer (score 0):

With `this` in plain JS, added `helloo` just for testing

```js
function CommentReply(el){
  //  `el` here is `this` passed from `onclick` is the reference to the element
  console.log(el.id);
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left">
  <div class="d-inline ">
    <i id="reply@{@item.Id}" class="bi bi-reply icon-cursor test-comment" onclick="CommentReply(this)">helloo</i>
  </div>                            
</div>
```

click on ***helloo*** and see console for id